# operand type does not match error

Tags: assembly

I have to learn Assembly for my university and i need to do this:

```
(a+b+c+1) *(a+b+c+1) /((a-b+d)*(a-b+d)).
```

When i try to create the exe file using the "tasm" command i get this messages:

```
**Error** lab1.ASM(14) Operand types do not match
**Error** lab1.ASM(15) Operand types do not match
**Warning* lab1.ASM(30) Open segment:Data
```

Here is my code:

```
assume cs:code,ds:data
data segment 
a db 1
b db 2
c db 3 
d db 4 
code segment 
start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov al,a
mov ah,0
add ax,b ;ax=a+b
add ax,c ;ax=a+b+c
add ax,1 ;ax=a+b+c+1
mov bx,ax ;bx=ax
mul bx ;dx:ax=(a+b+c+1) *(a+b+c+1)
mov al,a
mov ah,0
sub al,b ; al=a-b
add al,d ; al=a-b+d
mov bl,al ; bl=al
mul bl ; ax=(a-b+d)*(a-b+d)
mov bx,ax
div bx ; dx:ax :bx =(a+b+c+1) *(a+b+c+1) /((a-b+d)*(a-b+d))
mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: It is not at all clear "what you need to do", nor is it clear which lines your error messages refer to.

Answer (score 0):

`AX` is word-size; `A` and `B` are byte-size.

observe that you don't have the same problem later on in the code where you subtract `B` from `AL` for instance (both byte-size)